# public key certificate

Tags: security

what role does public key certificate play in public key cryptosystem?

Comment: Flagged - not a programming question

Comment: @Robin Green,where should ask?

Comment: @Fatima - Try Quora.com or Yahoo Answers. Or ask a librarian to help you.

Comment: @Robin Green - while public key certificates are a broad topic, it's something that many programmers have to know to perform their job. I myself have had trouble understanding these concepts while learning about WCF Security, and a few basic questions on this forum would have come in very handy.

Comment: @Robin Green-I try Quora.com but I see this messege"Sorry, you must have an invitation to create an account on Quora." what does it mean? what must I do?

Comment: A better place to try for anything security related is http://security.stackexchange.com/. Although for this type of basics question, you might be better off simply heading to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public key refers to a cryptographic system where there are two parts: the public key (which is given out freely) and the private key. Anyone can use the public key to encrypt a piece of information. However, to decrypt this information you need to use the private key. This is a powerful technique to ensure that information can only be read by the intended recipient (who would be the private key holder).

The "certificate" is a means of relating the public key with a specific identify. So for example, a company "Widgets Incorporated" provides the certificate with a public key, and an external certificate authority confirms that this certificate really does belong to "Widgets Incorporated" (and not, for example, "Credit Card Scams-R-Us"). The external authority signs the certificate with a [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) to confirm that it is genuinely from the identified company, and that it has not been tampered with.

Comment: thanks. but in this cryptographic system someone may access to public keys and change or replace them? does certificate solve this problem?how?

Comment: @Fatima - I've added another sentence to address the question about tampering.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in reading http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html or a similar book.

Comment: I have some books but I become confused.I don't underestand it very well and it is not homework.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "public key certificate". X.509 certificates, used in Public Key Infrastructure, contain a public key of a keypair and certain other information. The certificate is signed (using PKI means and public key algorithm).

Overall the question is too broad and good reading is recommended. For example, we have an [explanation article](http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1951.php) on our site.

Comment: Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS,thanks. but in this cryptographic system someone may access to public keys and change or replace them? does certificate solve this problem?how?

Comment: @Fatima Public keys are called "public" cause everyone can have access to them. They can not be replaced cause they are part of the certificate, and the certificate is signed. I suggest that you do read materials and take a course if you need to deepen your understanding.